# Как правильно реализовать swap элементов массива

Tags: ios, swift

```
var newArr1 = NSMutableArray()
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newArr1.addObject(Int(arc4random_uniform(100)))
    }
    print(newArr1)
       for (var i = 0; i < newArr1.count-1; i++) {
        if(Int(newArr1.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSNumber) > Int(newArr1.objectAtIndex(i+1) as! NSNumber )) {
            //print(newArr1)
            print(newArr1.objectAtIndex(i), newArr1.objectAtIndex(i+1))
            swap(&newArr1[i], &newArr1[i+1])

        }else{
            print("1 < 2")
        }
```

как правильно реализовать свап элементов? чтобы сравнивались каждые 2 элемента, т.е 1и2, 3и4 и тд. В моем случае работает некорректно,например, если в начале массива будет самое большое число, то оно заменит все остальные элементы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если 1 и 2, 3 и 4, то просто сделайте шаг в цикле `i+=2`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < newArr1.count-1; i+=2) {
```

Ну и проверку, если количество элементов будет нечетным.

---

**Swift 3**:

```
for i in stride(from: 0, through: newArr1.count - 1, by: 2) {
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я на самом деле так пробовал, только писал i+2, вместо написанного Вами i+=2 и результат вводил меня в недоумение)))